# Conditional type is inferred differently with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

Typescript infers the conditional type (with disabled distribution) differently when a generic type is passed.

```
type Box<T> = { a: T };

// Conditional type with disabled distribution using tuple.
type CondType<T> = [T] extends [string | number]
    ? Box<T> : false;

class Test<T extends string | number> {
    public constructor(private value: T) {}

    // CondType<T> is not inferred as Box<string | number>
    public one(param: CondType<T>): void {
        param; // type is false | Box<T>
    }

    // This works as expected
    public two(param: CondType<string | number>): void {
        param; // type is Box<string | number>
    }
}
```

Why is this? and is there a way around it?

Comment: This is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132

Comment: you may use `param: CondType<T extend (string | number)>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a missing feature in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132) for the relevant feature request.  Its status is "awaiting more feedback" so it might be a good idea to go there, give it a , and describe your use case for why you need this, if you think it's especially compelling (it might need to be a little more motivated than the example here, though).

The issue is that the compiler does not consult [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) when evaluating [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend upon as-yet-unspecified generic type parameters.  Instead, the compiler just *defers* the evaluation entirely.  So even though `T` is constrained to `string | number`, the compiler does not use this information to eagerly take the true branch of `CondType<T>` and result in `Box<T>`.  It stays `CondType<T>` which is not known to be assignable to `Box<T>` for unspecified `T`.

---

Possible workarounds until and unless ms/TS#23132 is addressed:

Well, since in fact `CondType<T>` will definitely evaluate to `Box<T>`, you could just use that type instead:

```
  public three(param: Box<T>): void {
    param; // Box<T> of course
  }
```

although I'd imagine that this might not work for your actual use case (and this is why I'd say any comment in ms/TS#23132 should feature a situation that can't be trivially worked around like this).

The general purpose workaround for situations where *you* know more about the type of some expression than the *compiler* does is to use [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  Essentially you are taking the job of verifying type safety away from the compiler and taking the responsibility onto yourself:

```
  public four(param: CondType<T>): void {
    const paramAsserted = param as Box<T>; // just assert it
  }
```

This will let you move ahead as desired, although the danger is that you might have accidentally lied to the compiler; let's say you later change `class Test<T extends string | number> {/*...*/}` to `class Test<T extends string | number | boolean> {/*...*/}`.  That type assertion will no longer be true, but the compiler will not report an error.  After all, the compiler cannot tell the difference between when `CondType<T>` is assignable to `Box<T>` for generic `T` and when it's not assignable.  So you have to be careful with type assertions, and double check that what you're asserting is true.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwDwBUB8UC8UDeUCGAXFClAL4DcAUFQPS1QDCcAdgCYCWwHr+ANlFCQoAdy4ALKJwDO+AEZ8IbKR2nAAThzkBXbqyjbpHFgHNB2sIoB0VIdGbsU4CKgzYA2igC6UCAmAQ7NJQ7mqaplAAPlAs2gC2chDqXlRQUAD8sIiuUMQAZvzSENRUAMZ8+NLBKBBqqL7+gWzBYcZm0bEJSRg4qVBg2gocpVClrGHapcBw6gAUYJoAbvgBUMt82hDEKACUuOQ0afRMrGxOkDmqMXDAUMZ5SepKBMHwyK0RHfGJ6mh9A0MRqwIPN8Op8HFiA4zs5XDtiIs4BxlL00mkwGCIRQoMc7HdggU+EUollkOg+mQaH1jihxFcRDMANbBSoNSBTJT-QZ8YaCBmg8GQk6OWEfdoxb7deFrJEovrozFxbG45z40lIMUkzo-P5pSlcwGCcRPEEYwXEN5whGy3Dy-qKikGnkjPJwbRzM0QqGnc4udDSxHI21o0bjW6euIAQSqSQCymwEZe6vQyoYACtDLdKkV1LcuI6aGQgA)

Comment: The odd part is that if you remove the tuple wrapping in the conditional type, it seems to work fine.